# Expanding the Angular Material Data Table Header Row to Match Row Content Width?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, typescript

### Relevant Feature Request to the Angular Material Data Table

https://github.com/angular/components/issues/16959

[In this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-minimal-material-table-demo-overflow?file=src%2Fstyles.css) with a sticky header scrolling the contents works fine for the rows when only looking at the initial viewport.

However when panning to the right and scrolling the rows they bleed through the header, because the header does not expand.

Also the data table row lines do not expand passed the viewport width.
How do we fix this?

[Added a minimal demo inline in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57773529/getting-a-flex-container-to-expand-to-fit-the-total-width-of-all-the-contained-i) using pure CSS and HTML.

This is the CSS for the `mat-header-row`:

```
    mat-footer-row, mat-header-row, mat-row {
        display: flex;
        border-width: 0;
        border-bottom-width: 1px;
        border-style: solid;
        align-items: center;
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }
```

It only expands to the width of the viewport, so the `mat-header-cell`s overflow when they have a total width that is greater than the viewport.

This is a screenshot a `mat-row` in the developer console.  As can be seen the row is only the width of the viewport but the contents of the row is much wider than the viewport:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You experience this because `.mat-header-row` didn't get the width increase which you applied to `.mat-cell`

To **resolve**, need to assign the 200rem width to this class also (inside **styles.css**):

```
the .mat-cell ,.mat-header-row {
  min-width: 200rem;
}
```

forked your [stackblitz with this change here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-minimal-material-table-demo-overflow-meck2j)

Comment: If have another case where it still does not quite work and I think it's because the header is a flex box, so we have to use flex basis to set the min width ... I think ... I'm investigating it right now ... The problem I'm seeing is that `mat-header-row` is only the width of the viewport still, so the `mat-header-cell`s overflow to the right of it.  I need the `mat-header-row` which is a flex container, to expand to the width of the cells.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57773529/getting-a-flex-container-to-expand-to-fit-the-total-width-of-all-the-contained-i

Comment: In the above SO post I put a pure css and html demo of what I'm seeing.